# Gmail API Push Notifications with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, push-notification, gmail, gmail-api

I'm making a web-app with Nodejs and [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) that notifies me about E-mails received in a certain label.

After some research, I found this guide: [Push Notifications | Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

But I've come to a halt as I cannot understand what to do after [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).

The `watch()` function works fine and gives me the correct response.

Here is my full code (The authorization part is taken from the [Gmail API's quickstart guide for Nodejs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const readline = require('readline');
const {
    google
} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Gmail API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), (auth) => {
        listUnreadMsgs(auth), watchMyLabel(auth)
    });
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const {
        client_secret,
        client_id,
        redirect_uris
    } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            // Store the token to disk for later program executions
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) return console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}
/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function listUnreadMsgs(auth) {
    var gmail = google.gmail({
        auth: auth,
        version: 'v1'
    });

    gmail.users.history.list({
        userId: "me",
        startHistoryId: 2982217,
        labelId: 'Label_8061975816208384485'
    }, async function (err, results) {
        // https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list#response
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        const latest = await results.data.history[results.data.history.length - 1].messages;
        gmail.users.messages.get({
            userId: 'me',
            id: latest[latest.length - 1].id
        }, (err, res) => {
            if (res.data.labelIds.includes('UNREAD')) {
                console.log(res.data.snippet);
            } else {
                console.log('No unread messages here!');
            }
        });

    });
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function watchMyLabel(auth) {
    const gmail = google.gmail({
        version: 'v1',
        auth
    });
    const res = await gmail.users.watch({
        userId: 'me',
        requestBody: {
            labelIds: ['Label_8061975816208384485', 'UNREAD'],
            labelFilterAction: "include",
            topicName: 'projects/quickstart-1593237046786/topics/notifications'
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the output:

[image: And here]

**What to do next?**

**TL;DR**

- I'm making a push notification system from Gmail API with Nodejs.
- I don't understand what to do after [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_response)
- I want to `console.log` the changes in my mailbox in real-time, without restarting the nodejs app.

Thank you. Please help =).

*EDIT* : I have no prior understanding of webhooks so it would be really good if anyone could explain me exactly what to do next in my case.

Comment: Thanks for this question because it's better than any quickstart guide I've seen for getting `watch` working on node!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the next step was to use the Google Cloud Pub/Sub API: [Receiving messages using Pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull).

Ensure proper authorization and user access.